# Create objects from input files in Apache Flink

Tags: scala, apache-flink

I have a data set which is structured by folders and files. The folder / file structure itself is important for the data analysis.

The Structure of the data set:

```
folder1
   +-----file11
            +-----column1
            +-----column2
```

Every file contains data which describe one object. The format of the files is consistent. Its basically a csv-file with two columns. The two columns should be represented as sequence of tuples in the resulting object.

The size of the files is pretty small. Only up to 20 kb. Every folder contains about 200 files.

The desired output object should be:

```
{
    a: "folder1",              // name of parent folder
    b: "file11",               // name of content file
    c: Seq[(String, String)]   // content of file1
}
```

How do I handle the read of this data set in Scala?

Comment: How many of those directories do you have?
Is it gigabytes of data you are planning to read like this?

Comment: I have around 3500 of those directories. Each is them contains roughly 1.5 mb of data from 200 files. So the total data set is around 5 gb.

Comment: Then I would recommend the second approach I've suggested in my answer.
Please let me know if you need more help implementing it.

Comment: That's what I though too. So I will sit down this evening / tomorrow and work through it. Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two approaches to solve this:

a) If the data from the folders is very small (less than a few megabytes) you can do the reading locally and use the `ExecutionEnvironment.fromCollection()` method to bring the data into the Flink job.

b) You create a custom InputFormat. An InputFormat allows to parse custom file formats. In your case, I would extend the `TextInputFormat` and overwrite the `readRecord()` method. This method is giving you each line in the files as a String.
You can then manually parse the data from the String and return the parsed result with the directory information in a Tuple3. You can access the path from the `filePath` variable.
For recursively reading files with `FileInputFormat`s, there is the `recursive.file.enumeration` configuration value.

Comment: I extended my custom `TextInputFormat` from `org.apache.flink.api.java.io.TextInputFormat` (there is also `org.apache.flink.api.java.record.io.TextInputFormat`, the first one is the correct one?). The first thing that I noticed is, that I only can return a `String` in the `readRecord(..)` method. But this is fine for me. The second and more important issue I have now is, `super.getFilePath()` does not return the path to the current file, more the path I passed as the input directory.

Comment: Hi,
don't use the `org.apache.flink.api.java.record.io.TextInputFormat`, its from an older Flink API.
You should be able to set the return type of readRecord() to a different type. The reason why it has to be "String" is because the DelimitedInputFormat sets the return type to String: `class TextInputFormat extends DelimitedInputFormat<String>`.
But maybe you can extend from the DelimitedInputFormat and set it to the type you need.

Comment: Getting the actual file path is harder than expected. Sorry.
It is stored in the `FileInputSplit` class, which is passed to the InputFormat in the `open(FileInputSplit)` method, but it seems that you can not access it.
To fix this, I would introduce a new field into the `FileInputFormat` of flink, name `currentSplit`. Then, you can get the path from the current split. But for doing this, we would need to change the source of Flink.

Would you like to contribute to Flink and fix this or should I do it for you?

Comment: I just created a pull request for this new feature. Thanks for the support.

Comment: Regarding my original question: I guess I was not specific enough. The directory structure of my data set is not the only thing I want to keep. I also need to preserve the ordering of input files line wise. Do I have to make in implementation which derives from `FileInputFormat`? Because in my case I need to read in the whole file at once I guess?

Comment: Yes, the `DelimitedInputFormat` will split the data in the files by a delimiter (usually `\n`) but in your case you'll probably read the entire file and then emit records. The `FileInputFormat` is then the right base class to derive from.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the above posts, I was able to create custom FileInputFormat class to read excel.xlsx files and stream it in flink. The code is as below

```
/*
 * Custom format output I was expecting from the records converted into records
 */
case class ExcelSheetData(Module : Double, StartTime : String, EndTime : String,....,  FileName : String)

/*
 * Custom class to read Excel spreadsheet using flink FileInputFormat class 
 */
class ExcelInputFormat extends FileInputFormat[ExcelSheetData]{

    var running : Boolean = false
    var excelData : Seq[ExcelSheetData] = null
    unsplittable = true

    override def open(fileSplit : FileInputSplit) = {

        println(fileSplit.getPath.toString.drop(6))
        val myFile = new File(fileSplit.getPath.toString.drop(6)) 
        val fileName = fileSplit.getPath.toString.drop(6)

        val fis = new FileInputStream(myFile)
        try{
            val myWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis)

            // println(s"Sheet Name: ${mySheet.getSheetName()}")
            // reading multiple sheets having identical data
            val mySheets = myWorkbook.iterator().asScala   
            val exData = for(s <- mySheets
                            if(s.getSheetName() == "Sheet1" || s.getSheetName() == "Sheet")) yield  {
                            val rowItr = s.rowIterator().asScala
                                for(e <- rowItr
                                    if(e.getRowNum() > 5 && e.getCell(1).getCellType() == 0)) yield {
                                    (e.getCell(1).getDateCellValue(), e.getCell(2).getDateCellValue(), ......,
                                    ,fileName)
                            }
                }

            excelData = exData.toSeq.flatten.map( record => {ExcelSheetData(record._1, record._2.toString, record._3.toString, record._4, record._5, record._6, record._7, record._8, record._9)})

            running = if(excelData.length >= 1) true else false

        } finally { fis.close()}

    }

    override def nextRecord(reuse: ExcelSheetData): ExcelSheetData = { 
        val head = excelData.head 
        excelData = excelData.tail 
        running = if (excelData.length == 0) false else true 
        head 
    }

    override def reachedEnd(): Boolean = ! running  

}

/*
 * Initialize custom class to read Excel Input
 */
val excelInput = new ExcelInputFormat()

// Read excel data into flink stream
val excelData = senv.readFile(excelInput, ExcelFilePath, FileProcessingMode.PROCESS_CONTINUOUSLY, 1000)
                            .uid("Excel File Read")

//Windowing code down below...
```

Answer (score 0):

The HadoopOffice library has native support for the Flink Table API as well as a Flink DataSource/DataSink for Excel files.

https://github.com/ZuInnoTe/hadoopoffice/wiki